# How to pull data from MT5 and create multiple pandas data frame variables from a list

Tags: python, pandas, metatrader5

I'm trying to modify my code to loop through the currency pairs in the "symbols" list, pulling data from MT5 and creating a pandas data frame for each item. At the moment, it only works when I specifically state one particular currency pair, in this case AUDCAD.

I want the data from "AUDCAD" to be saved as pandas data frame Table_1, "AUDCHF" as table_2, "AUDJPY" as table_3, etc. So I can simply add or remove currency pairs from the symbols list at will, instead of duplicating code for each pair.

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd

mt5.initialize()  # connect to MetaTrader 5

Symbols = ['AUDCAD', 'AUDCHF', 'AUDJPY', 'AUDNZD', 'AUDUSD', 'CADCHF', 'CADJPY', 'CHFJPY', 'GBPAUD', 'GBPCAD',
           'GBPCHF', 'GBPJPY', 'GBPNZD', 'GBPUSD', 'EURAUD', 'EURCAD', 'EURCHF', 'EURGBP', 'EURJPY', 'EURNZD',
           'EURUSD', 'NZDCAD', 'NZDCHF', 'NZDJPY', 'NZDUSD', 'USDCAD', 'USDCHF', 'USDJPY']

AUD_CAD = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("AUDCAD", mt5.TIMEFRAME_D1, 0, 100)
Table_1 = pd.DataFrame(AUD_CAD)[["time", "open", "high", "low", "close"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your core logic in a loop, iterating over your list of symbols:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd

mt5.initialize()  # connect to MetaTrader 5

symbols = ['AUDCAD', 'AUDCHF', 'AUDJPY', 'AUDNZD', 'AUDUSD', 'CADCHF', 'CADJPY', 'CHFJPY', 'GBPAUD', 'GBPCAD',
           'GBPCHF', 'GBPJPY', 'GBPNZD', 'GBPUSD', 'EURAUD', 'EURCAD', 'EURCHF', 'EURGBP', 'EURJPY', 'EURNZD',
           'EURUSD', 'NZDCAD', 'NZDCHF', 'NZDJPY', 'NZDUSD', 'USDCAD', 'USDCHF', 'USDJPY']

prices = {}

for symbol in symbols:
    data = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos(symbol, mt5.TIMEFRAME_D1, 0, 100)
    prices[symbol] = pd.DataFrame(data)[["time", "open", "high", "low", "close"]]
```

Note that I changed your variable names, including making them start with lowercase letters.  Convention that's worth following suggests that names that start with uppercase letters be reserved for class and other type names.

After running this code, you will have prices for all of your symbols in the `prices` dictionary.  You can then get the prices for a particular symbol via:

```
gbpnzd_prices = prices['GBPNZD']
```

Comment: Thanks, that works really well, but I'm having problems accessing the prices data. My original code works fine with a single data frame, but I'm getting a key error for the close value when trying to access the dictionary. Is there something I need to do the dictionary before accessing it?    Table_1["ema_12"] = Table_1 ["close"].ewm(span = fast_ema_period, min_periods = fast_ema_period).mean()
Table_1["ema_26"] = Table_1 ["close"].ewm(span = slow_ema_period, min_periods = slow_ema_period).mean()

Comment: No, there isn't anything you should have to do.  I would suggest that you get a good look at what your data actually looks like.  You can just do `print(prices)`, or import the `pprint` module and do `pprint.pprint(prices)` to get a cleaner display.  If you still have problems, I'd suggest that you update your question, as it's hard to read code in comments.  Put an "UPDATE:" heading at the bottom of the question and then add on from there. If you get a printout of your data and then have questions about it, paste it into the question.